# ブロック内で引数適用も省略して書ける？

Tags: ruby

```
arr = ["foo", "bar"].map{ |s| s.upcase }
```

このコードは以下のように短縮できます。

```
arr = ["foo", "bar"].map(&:upcase)
```

---

では、

```
arr2 = ["foo", "bar"].map{ |s| my_method(s) }
```

このようなコードを短縮して書く方法はありますか？
ない場合、そもそもこの書き方自体がruby的でないとかそういう事情があるのでしょうか？
(ダックタイピングするなり、該当クラスを継承した自分用クラスを作るなりしてs.my_methodの形にしたほうが良い？)

Comment: `"foo".puts`のような呼び出しができない（つまり該当オブジェクトのメソッドでない）からだと思いますが（望む答えですかね？）

Comment: 質問には関係無いですけどputsの場合eachを使うべきなのでは？(適用結果をコレクションしてアサインする意味がほとんどない）

Comment: @BLUEPIXY >該当オブジェクトのメソッドでない &でto_procしても動かない理由がそれであるのはわかります。 メソッドの引数への単純な適用にも似たような略記イディオムがあるのかどうかが知りたいです。 >each そうですね…

Comment: 私はそういう略記イディオムがあるか知りませんので回答できませんが、多分無いような気がします。カスタムクラスのメソッドにしたり`pr=lambda{ |s| puts(s) }`, `["foo", "bar"].each(&pr)`はできますけど、略記したいのにコードを増やしてたらあんまり（再利用可能ならともかく）意味が無いかも。

Comment: ひょっとして related : [落ちていくRubyistのためのMethopオブジェクト](http://melborne.github.io/2014/04/20/extend-ampersand-magic-with-methop/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

以前Qiitaに書いたこの記事の内容と同じかもしれません。

[配列を順番に処理するとき、直接メソッドを呼ぶ代わりに"&method(:name)"を使う](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/dedb3b889ab226933ccf#%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E9%A0%86%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AB%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B6%E4%BB%A3%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%ABmethodname%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86)

> 配列を順番に処理するとき、直接メソッドを呼ぶ代わりに"&method(:name)"を使う
>
> 普通にブロックを書く方が一般的ですが、&method(:name)みたいな引数を渡すこともできます。

#### 普通に呼ぶ場合

```
def process_users
  users.each do |user|
    process_user(user)
  end
end

def process_user(user)
  send_mail_to(user)
  user.mail_sent_at = Time.now
  user.save
end
```

#### &method(:name)の形式で呼ぶ場合

```
def process_users
  users.each(&method(:process_user))
end

def process_user(user)
  send_mail_to(user)
  user.mail_sent_at = Time.now
  user.save
end
```